# Bind DropDownList SelectedValue from Enum

Tags: c#

I have enum for Salutation like

```
public enum SALUTATION
{
    MR = 1,
    MS = 2,
    MRS = 3,        
}
```

and in my `staff` class my `Salutation` property is like,

```
public SALUTATION Salutation
{
     get;
     set;
}
```

here, while editing the staff profile am just binding the datas from the database. For salutation I just tried binding the salutation like

```
ddlSalutation.SelectedValue = Enum.GetName(typeof(SALUTATION), staff.Salutation);
```

but it binds the selectedValue as `-1` always. how can I bind the exact value in the ddl selected item. can anyone help me here..

in the page load event am just binding the ddl source as

```
 Hashtable hashSalutation = Utilities.GetEnumList(typeof(SALUTATION));
            ddlSalutation.DataSource = hashSalutation;
            ddlSalutation.DataTextField = "value";
            ddlSalutation.DataValueField = "key";
            ddlSalutation.DataBind();

            ddlSalutation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Salutation", "-1"));

public Hashtable GetEnumList(Type enumeration)
    {
        string[] names = Enum.GetNames(enumeration);
        Array values = Enum.GetValues(enumeration);
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            ht.Add(Convert.ToInt32(values.GetValue(i)).ToString(), names[i]);
        }
        return ht;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried `ddlSalutation.SelectedValue =  staff.Salutation;`

Comment: What are the pair of (Text, Value) of the DropDownList? It seems that you're trying to asign the incorrect value, as GetName will return MR, MS or MRS not the value

Comment: or try `ddlSalutation.SelectedItem = staff.Salutation` if not `ddlSalutation.Text = staff.Salutation`

Comment: @Talha: I tried its showing error like "cannot implicitly convert SALUTATION to string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set this as your datasource

```
ddSalutation.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Salutations));
```

Then for selected value

```
ddlSalutation.SelectedValue = staff.Salutation.ToString();
```